# Drupal 7: Customize hook_view for Debut Event module is not working

Tags: drupal-7

I am trying to add a custom message under the text of event description,
I tried to use hook_view like this:

```
function debut_event_view($node, $view_mode) {
         $message= "This is a message";
         $node->dynamicinfo= $message;
         $node->content['dynamicinfo'] = array(
'#markup' => $message,
'#weight' => 2,
);
}
```

but, the message didn't show up under the description when I view the event
isn't the debut event a content type module ?? is my way to do it wrong ??

in general, whats the best way to append a message to the content type view ?

Answer (score 1):

You can only use hook_view() if you are the module that defines the node type in hook_node_info(). You probably want to use something more like [hook_node_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7).

Comment: I am a little bit confused, what's the different between module & base ? when do we use the base of content type as hooks ? and when do we use module name as hook ?

I've used hook_view() inside the module that declared the node type in the hook_node_info()

if use the module name nothing happen
if i use the base name, i get show stopper error that stops the whole website